# Can I move/watch my PlayStation Videos without my PlayStation?

Tags: playstation-plus

PlayStation Plus allows me to download/watch Movies/TV on my PlayStation, once I purchase them from the store.

However, I will be going on a trip for a week, and I wanted to download some movies to watch during the week. Obviously, I won't be taking my PS with me, so is there any way I can access them on my laptop/move them onto a USB, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the list of compatible devices - [PlayStation Video compatible devices](https://www.playstation.com/en-gb/get-help/help-library/services/playstation-video/playstation-video-compatible-devices/).

To access you videos on laptop you need to open ps store web site and go to 'My Videos', but looks like downloading is not allowed. However, there are some browser extensions which allow to download any streamed video.